# PyParsing: Parsing Cisco's "show ip bgp"

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a string as below using PyParsing.

```
R1# show ip bgp
BGP table version is 2, local router ID is 1.1.1.1
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i -     internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
> 10.1.1.0/24      192.168.1.2              0             0 200 i
```

Note that LocPrf value is empty but it can be a number.

```
ipField = Word(nums, max=3)
ipAddr = Combine(ipField + "." + ipField + "." + ipField + "." + ipField)
status_code = Combine(Optional(oneOf("s d h * r")) + ">" + Optional(Literal("i"))
prefix = Combine(ipAddr + Optional(Literal("/") + Word(nums,max=2)))
next_hop = ipAddr
med = Word(nums)
local_pref = Word(nums) | White()
path = Group(OneOrMore(Word(nums)))
origin = oneOf("i e ?")
```

This is the grammar.

```
g = status_code + prefix + next_hop + med + local_pref + Suppress(Word(nums)) + Optional(path) + origin
```

I just need to parse the Bold line. But this is not parsing it properly. It assigns Weight value to LocPrf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look over the following code example (which I will include in the next pyparsing release). You should be able to adapt it to your application:

```
from pyparsing import col,Word,Optional,alphas,nums,ParseException

table = """\
12345678901234567890
COLOR      S   M   L
RED       10   2   2
BLUE           5  10
GREEN      3       5
PURPLE     8"""

# function to create column-specific parse actions
def mustMatchCols(startloc,endloc):
    def pa(s,l,t):
        if not startloc <= col(l,s) <= endloc:
            raise ParseException(s,l,"text not in expected columns")
    return pa

# helper to define values in a space-delimited table
def tableValue(expr, colstart, colend):
    return Optional(expr.copy().addParseAction(mustMatchCols(colstart,colend)))


# define the grammar for this simple table
colorname = Word(alphas)
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0])).setName("integer")
row = (colorname("name") + 
        tableValue(integer, 11, 12)("S") + 
        tableValue(integer, 15, 16)("M") + 
        tableValue(integer, 19, 20)("L"))

# parse the sample text - skip over the header and counter lines
for line in table.splitlines()[2:]:
    print
    print line
    print row.parseString(line).dump()
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your response. I understand the idea behind this and it should work for me as well. However, could you explain the function "pa" and how the values are passed to it?

Comment: "pa" is a "parse action", called during the parsing process when the expression the parse action is attached to.  At parse time, when the expression matches, then the string, parse location, and parsed tokens are passed to the parse action (the `s`, `l`, and `t` arguments that you see on `pa`). Rather than write 3 different parse actions that differ only in the start and end column indices, I wrote a parse action factory method `mustMatchCols` that creates the custom parse actions based on the arguments passed to it. The resulting function is attached to the different expressions.

Comment: Hi Paul, Can we set a value (say, 0) instead of raising an exception if text is not found?

Comment: Rather than do something this low-level, I would add a parse action on `row`. Iterate through the list of expected keys, and if one is missing, insert it into the tokens as if you were storing to a dict. `for key in "SML": if key not in t: t[key] = 0`.